# AWS EC2: Why does ".NET Beanstalk HostManager v1.0.1.1" keep coming back

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I keep killing the default instance and it keeps coming back.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that you are facing a specific issue I've seen several users stumbling over, but your question is a bit short on detail, so I might misinterpret your problem in fact.

### Background

The [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) allows you to deploy applications to [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), which is a [Platform as a Service (PaaS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) offering allowing you to *quickly deploy and manage applications in the AWS cloud*:

> You simply upload your application, and Elastic Beanstalk
>   automatically handles the deployment details of capacity provisioning,
>   load balancing, auto-scaling, and application health monitoring.

You deploy an application to Elastic Beanstalk into an [Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.components.html) comprised of an [Elastic Load Balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and resp. [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) policies, which together ensure your application will keep running even if the EC2 instance is having trouble servicing the requests for whatever reason (see [Architectural Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html) for an explanation and illustration how these components work together).

That is, your [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances are managed by default, so you don't *need* to administrate the infrastructure yourself, but the specific characteristic of this AWS PaaS variation is that you still *can* do that:

> At the same time, with Elastic Beanstalk, you retain full control over
>   the AWS resources powering your application and can access the
>   underlying resources at any time.

Now that's exactly what you unintentionally did by terminating the EC2 instance via a mechanism outside of the Elastic Beanstalk service, which the load balancer detects and, driven by those auto scaling policies, triggers the creation of a replacement instance.

### Solution

Long story short, you need to terminate the Elastic Beanstalk environment instead, as illustrated in section *Step 6: Clean Up* within the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Walkthrough](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.Walkthrough.html) (there is a dedicated section for the Elastic Beanstalk service within the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/#eb)).

You can also do this via Visual Studio, as explained in step 11 at the bottom of [How to Deploy the PetBoard Application Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/deploy-the-petboard-application-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk.html):

> To delete the deployment, expand the Elastic Beanstalk node in AWS
>   Explorer, and then right-click the subnode for the deployment. Click
>   Delete. AWS Elastic Beanstalk will begin the deletion process, which
>   may take a few minutes. If you specified an notification email address
>   the deployment, AWS Elastic Beanstalk will send status notifications
>   for the delete process to this address.